# How to Compare a Portion of MySQL String with PHP String?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare a PHP String (123) with a portion of MySQL String (Suppose: BB123).

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `site_id` LIKE '".$row["bs_id_site"]."'");
```

I have used this above query.

But it is not returning the result because of Alpha String (Like: "BB") inside `site_id`.

What can be a solution in such case, while comparing PHP String with a part of MySQL String?

If I would compare a Part of PHP String I could use % sign, but what will be the case for MySQL String?

Comment: do u want just like this where site_id like '123'

Answer (score 1):

You can try;

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `site_id` LIKE '__".$row["bs_id_site"]."'");
```

see example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bff/3/0

But you really should not be using mysql_* since these are depreciated,

use msqli_* or PDO instead - [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

if your PHP string is;

```
$site_id = 'UK17001';
```

then use;

```
substr($site_id, 2);
```

Comment: My Site ID's are like: US17001, UK17393... and My $row["bs_id_site"] returns like: 17001, 17393... In such case How to compare, can you tell me please?